# skaffold using external docker image without build

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, skaffold

We are using skaffold for our kubernetes deployment and don't need the feature of building a docker container for every microservice, since we are building a base docker image from our microservice monorepo.

Right now, we have a dockerfile for each service which looks like this:

```
FROM microservice-base-image:latest
WORKDIR <service>
CMD ["node", "."]
```

This brings the problem, that for every change in our base image skaffold builds and pushes n times docker images, which are the size of the base image.

Is there any way to tell skaffold to just use our base docker image without building a separate one for each microservice, so that we can adjust our base image in a way to start the specific index file via an `ENTRYPOINT`?

We already tried the following, but skaffold complains about that the image can not be pulled, even though we are logged in into the private docker registry.

skaffold.yaml

```
  apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
  kind: Config
  
  profiles:
    - name: localhost
      deploy:
        kubectl:
          manifests:
            - ./infra/k8s/tmp/*
    - name: staging
      deploy:
        kubectl:
          manifests:
            - ./infra/k8s/tmp/*
  
  deploy:
    kubectl:
      manifests:
        - ./infra/k8s/tmp/*
```

service-1-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX-service-1-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX-service-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX-service-1
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <our-private-registry-secret>
      containers:
        - name: $CI_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX-service-1
          image: <accountid>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/microservice-base-image:latest
```

Skaffold log of both `skaffold dev` and `skaffold run --default-repo <accountid>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com -p $CI_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX`

```
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/staging-service-1-depl: container staging-service-1 is waiting to start: <accountid>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/microservice-base-image:latest can't be pulled
    - pod/staging-service-1-6bf9b46c68-jpmnt: container staging-service-1 is waiting to start: <accountid>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/microservice-base-image:latest can't be pulled
 - deployment/staging-service-1-depl failed. Error: container staging-service-1 is waiting to start: <accountid>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/microservice-base-image:latest can't be pulled.
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold only does image replacements for images that it built.  You have no images configured in your `skaffold.yaml` and so no image replacement will occur.

Skaffold does provide for expressing dependencies between images, so that you can say that [one image requires another image as a base image](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/08b48de8a4e35fa83c0bc18b578decd13db640e3/examples/microservices/skaffold.yaml#L5-L9).

Instead of building N microservice images that just set the `WORKDIR`, you could just use your base image as the only image and set the [`container.workingDir`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#container-v1-core) in your Kubernetes manifests to decide which microservice should be used.

That said, your current images setup has a disadvantage that a change in a single microservice will require redeploying all of your microservices.  Having each image include only its direct requirements means that only changed images will be redeployed, which results in faster redeploys.